# El opacity se aplica también al formulario, no solo a la imagen de fondo

Tags: html, css

Tengo una página de login en mi sistema y estoy aplicando una imagen de fondo a dicha página. La idea es aplicar opacity para dejar la imagen transparente y que el formulario destaque por sobre la imagen.

Mi problema es que al aplicar opacity a la imagen, también se aplica al formulario. He intentado solucionarlo por medio de CSS, pero no lo he logrado.

***Código CSS de página login***

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background: #bbc8d6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.80;
  background-size: cover;
}

#container form {
  background: #008080;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#container form img {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#container form input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #85929e;
  text-align: center;
}

#container form input:hover {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #004aae;
  text-align: center;
}

#container form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #0975ce;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #0975ce;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ff6600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-image: 
    url("https://offloadmedia.feverup.com/madridsecreto.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/27172709/planes-gratis-madrid.jpg"); '>
  <section id="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>

      <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
      <input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Contraseña">
      <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Le estás aplicando opacidad a todo el body, CSS significa Cascading Style Sheet... cascading, porque las propiedades se heredan hacia abajo. Si usas `color: red; font-weight: bold;` en el body no te extrañaría que luego tus div y párrafos tengan la fuente roja no? Pasa lo mismo con la opacidad... los atributos se heredan. Simplemente machaca el valor a continuación por ejemplo: `section { opacity: 1; }`. Aunque personalmente, yo reestructuraría un poco la página, no me gusta aplicar estilos así al propio body, es mejor usar un div con width y height 100% para ello, queda más limpio.

Comment: Realice el ajuste que me indicas, pero continua aplicando el opacity al form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como [Benito-B](/users/188830) [mencionó](/q/602280#comment1063825_602280), se está aplicando el *opacity* a todo el *body*, por lo tanto es de esperar que se aplique la propiedad incluso al formulario.

Lo que se puede hacer es convertir el color de fondo a rgb (con cualquier herramienta que convierta hexadecimal a rgb), y luego utilizar [la función rgb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb) pasando como último argumento la transparencia (*alpha*), y establecer esto como el *background-color* del *#container*, en este caso:

```css
background-color: rgb(187, 200, 214, 0.8); /*o ".8", que es lo mismo*/
```

<sub>Prestar atención al código comentado.</sub>

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  /*background: #bbc8d6;*/
  background-color: rgb(187, 200, 214, 0.8); /*transparencia de 0.8*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  /*opacity: 0.80;*/
  background-size: cover;
}

#container form {
  background: #008080;
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#container form img {
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#container form input {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #85929e;
  text-align: center;
}

#container form input:hover {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #004aae;
  text-align: center;
}

#container form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #0975ce;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #0975ce;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ff6600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body style='background-image: 
    url("https://offloadmedia.feverup.com/madridsecreto.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/27172709/planes-gratis-madrid.jpg"); '>
  <section id="container">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>

      <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
      <input type="password" name="clave" placeholder="Contraseña">
      <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
```

Tal como recomendaron, es además conveniente reestructurar el código para no mezclar los estilos *inline* con los CSS externos.